# Android Swipe to Minimize

Tags: android, popup, minimize

I have not found any documenton so I figured I would ask and see if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Many apps allow you to swipe diagonally down from top left to minimize into a popup window on my Galaxy Note 4 the list of apps that allow you to do this is endless from line app, to facebook. Chrome to every system application including texting, phone and so forth I am not finding any documention because I am not exactly sure what it falls under to include it in my application. If anybody has any good documention or tutorial links they can provide please do

Comment: Most likely, you are looking at a specific feature of the Galaxy Note 4, where Samsung modified Android with a multi-window implementation. Android N offers this for all Android devices. You can also use Samsung's mobile SDK to enable this for Samsung devices that support this feature.

Comment: Yes I have seen it on a few other devices but the answer you provided seems like the best however in N where is this feature located in the multi window or ?

Comment: Android N offers a split-screen multi-window mode by default, a picture-in-picture mode for Android TV, and a freeform mode (think: desktop OS windows) that manufacturers can opt into. None quite match what you are describing, but they are the closest that you can get with Android itself (and that only with the upcoming N release).